# Is there a way to pause a jenkins pipeline periodic build?

Tags: jenkins

I have periodic builds set up with a jenkins pipeline job and I want to pause the automated builds temporarily. One option is to uncheck the "build periodically" checkbox, but then the schedule information gets cleared out. Is there a way to put the builds on hold but preserve the schedule info?

Update:
Adding screenshot of main pipeline job page.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the button <kbd>Disable Project</kbd> top-right on a project's main page.

#### UPDATE:

[image: Jenkins Disable Project]

And there's ***General*** → ***Build Triggers*** → ☐ *Disable this project* in a pipeline project's config.

Comment: Not seeing such a button. This is a pipeline job btw. Attached a screenshot to the original question.

Comment: @opike Does the user have restrictions on [_Job_: _Configure_](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security#Matrix-basedsecurity-Job)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'm the only user in this jenkins instance and I've never done anything to restrict access. Is that "Disable Project" button part of stock Jenkins or could it have come from an add-on? What version of jenkins are you on?

Comment: @opike It seems to be a native Jenkins option (there's no link to a plugin in the config option's inline help). My Jenkins' version can be seen at bottom-right of my screenshot ;).

Comment: Ah ok, my instance is version 2.46.1 - will try to upgrade and see if it shows up then.

Comment: Upgraded to 2.60.1 but it didn't matter. I chatted with a contractor and he suspects it's because I have a Jenkinsfile in github associated with the job. So now I'm considering adding code to my Jenkinsfile to look for an environment variable and will use the environment variable to control the behavior.

Comment: So to summarize the answer - if there is no separate Jenkinsfile, then the button shows up. With a Jenkinsfile, you'll need to roll your own pause mechanism.